# How to create a persistent connection to Kafka through Spring Boot web application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

Please excuse the ambiguity as I'm trying to be as clear as possible with the little knowledge that I have.

We have a Kafka cluster and the idea is to have a Spring Boot application to serve as the bridge between the Producers, Consumers and Kafka.

I've worked with simple REST, CRUD applications, in which I basically interact with the server on a request basis.

---

**Question:**

How do I go about creating a persistent connection between Spring and Kafka to send and receive messages?

Does the protocol matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kafka uses its own [binary protocol over TCP](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/protocol.html) for publishing messages to topics for polling messages with subscriptions.
For being able to connect to a Kafka cluster from a Spring Boot project, you may want to use [`spring-kafka`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/) which provides an implementation for this protocol:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

A minimalist set-up for a publisher and a consumer can be found in the official [spring-kafka docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#getting-started).

Answer (score 1):

I understand you wan to create a producer and consumer on a Kafka topic. Have you checked https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-stream